# Cannot figure out how to make Vite Work with Hostinger

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, vite

I'm having an error with my app deployment asking me to use "npm run dev" so that it can properly use vite in my build. But i cannot figure out how to do this. Any help is appreciated.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcI0w.png)

Tried to run my development server expecting vite to work

Comment: first thing, do you have npm installed in the project in the first place? Second is to check under scripts in your package.json file if the dev script includes the configuration for running Vite. Should look something like `dev : vite`

Comment: npm is not work in hostinger shared hosting bro you should run npm install and npm run prod in local and upload public folder on server

Comment: @shemjay Vite/npm is working on my local project just fine, I realized that the problem is persisting with the server not having any way to run npm dev (to my knowledge)

Comment: @PuneetSharma Thank you for your info, what folder am I supposed to upload to the server? Sorry, very new to this

Comment: @JamesBucsko then how do you pload your project to server and how you work in project

Comment: Think of `Hostinger` as the host that doesn't have `npm`, `node`, etc, so right before you upload your project, just run the `npm run prod` stuff locally, on your own PC. It will give you .css and .js files. Upload those files to your project (public directory)

Comment: If you are deploying from a code repository (eg github) remove the public/build from .gitignore so that the compiled assets are committed to source control.

Comment: Thank you @UnderDog and everyone who helped, Had to npm run build and then update my public folder. Appreciate all of you!

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `@vite` directive in laravel's views it actually tries to load `manifest.json` file from `public` directory. That file contains path to `.js` and `.css` (and others frontend related files) files, and `Laravel` load them. It needed because you may want build and deploy you frontend separately and when it happens (if it happens) you need to invalidate client's browser cache. When Vite builds your project it generates hashes along with files names and generate map original_filename => file_path for backend to understand which file is one.

You simply need to run `$ npm build` (which will runs full build and optimize your code) and deploy your `public` directory again.
When you run `$ npm run dev` it generates development not optimized build.

Comment: You are a life saver @Фарид Ахмедов Thanks a million! I got my website up and going, I didn't realize that run dev was used for testing purposes only. I appreciate the time you took to help me out!